# Split with multiple spaces and lists

Tags: list, split, tcl, spaces

I have this kind of line :

```
AA      BB  CC dd {ee ff} gg
```

I would like to split this line but with keeping the list like :

```
AA BB CC dd {ee ff} gg
```

so I tried `split` but I got multiple `{}` due to the multiple space between `AA` and `BB`

I triied also

```
set splitted_line [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $list]
```

but this command splits the list in `{ee` and `ff}`

What should I do to split my line properly ?

Comment: What are the _exact_ rules you want for when a group of words are to be kept together as one?

Comment: element between {} should stay together as a list, and the other words stay as single elements of the list : splitted_line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your line really will have `{`brace-quoted`}` words in it, you can probably get away with just treating it as a Tcl list directly. In that case, the first port of call for “cleaning it up” is to use `lrange`:

```
set splitted_line [lrange $list 0 end]
```

This will also convert a few other things, such as `"`double-quoted`"` words; I don't know if that's what you want.
<sub>Example session:</sub>

```
% set example {A   BB  CCC  {dd    ee} "ff $gg"    }
A   BB  CCC  {dd    ee} "ff $gg"    
% lrange $example 0 end
A BB CCC {dd    ee} {ff $gg}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the goal, to parse "Tcl compliant" lists. This commands works perfectly, thanks

Comment: If you've already got Tcl-compliant lists as strings, just use them as lists; all the list operations delegate to the same type conversion code under the hood anyway.